# Jinja2 for loop over a list of objects doesnt give preferred output

Tags: ansible, yaml, jinja2

The data.yml structure :

```
routingConfig:
   accessKeyId: AKIAVL34FWX5KFFSVSCND
   secretAccessKey: IglNnjk/iaR++DnQuNObAnrXsvsd9ZO+gJW5nZDd
   hostedZoneId: Z03431513GGUF3XEAQE5U
   recordSet:
      type: A
      ttl: 60
      resourceIp: 52.41.8.70
```

jinja2 template snippet to regenerate the yml structure :

```
routingConfig:
{% for key,value in routingConfig.items() if value.recordSet is not defined %}
{{ key|e }}: {{ value|e }}
{% endfor %}
recordSet:
{% for key,value in routingConfig.items() if value.recordSet is defined %}
{{ key|e }}: {{ value|e }}
{% endfor %}
```

The actual output :

```
routingConfig:
  recordSet: {u&#39;type&#39;: u&#39;A&#39;, u&#39;resourceIp&#39;: u&#39;52.71.3.72&#39;, 
  accessKeyId: AKIAVL34FWX5KFSTDFDFNCND
  secretAccessKey: IglNnjk/iaR++DnQuNObAnrXRrbfvdfvd9ZO+gJW5nZDd
  hostedZoneId: Z03431513GGUF3XEFBDVAQE5U
```

Expected output format :

```
routingConfig:
   accessKeyId: AKIAVL34FWX5KFFSVSCND
   secretAccessKey: IglNnjk/iaR++DnQuNObAnrXsvsd9ZO+gJW5nZDd
   hostedZoneId: Z03431513GGUF3XEAQE5U
   recordSet:
      type: A
      ttl: 60
      resourceIp: 52.41.8.70
```

Any suggestion to get the output in the same structure as in expected format?

```
{{ routingConfig | to_yaml(default_flow_style=False) | indent(2) }}
```

this gives the below yml format. But seems the indentation is not quite right

```
 routingConfig:
 accessKeyId: AKIAVL34FWX5KFDFBSTNCND
    recordSet:
      type: A
      ttl: 60
      resourceIp: 52.41.8.70
    secretAccessKey: IglNnjk/iaR++DnQuNObDFBAnrXsvsd9ZO+gJW5nZDd
    hostedZoneId: Z03431513GGUF3XEADGBDQE5U
```

Answer (score 5):

First of all, it does not make sense to use `|e` in a YAML template since that does HTML escaping, not YAML escaping. Use `|to_yaml` instead. Depending on your data (which you do not show), this may already suffice:

```yaml
routingConfig:
  {{ routingConfig | to_yaml(default_flow_style=False) | indent(2) }}
```

Mind that if you want to force a certain order of keys, you will need to output them separately:

```yaml
routingConfig:
  {% set c = routingConfig -%}
  accessKeyId: {{ c.accessKeyId | to_yaml }}
  secretAccessKey: {{ c.secretAccessKey | to_yaml }}
  hostedZoneId: {{ c.hostedZoneId | to_yaml }}
  recordSet:
    {% set r = c.recordSet -%}
    type: {{ r.type | to_yaml }}
    ttl: {{ r.ttl | to_yaml }}
    resourceIp: {{ r.resourceIp | to_yaml }}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it got curly braces in the output. Updated the question

Comment: @jsb9009 Edited answer to disallow flow style. Though be aware that the curly braces *are* valid YAML.

Comment: It works.. But the indentation does not :( . Updated the question

Comment: @jsb9009 It seems you did not indent the second line properly. In your edit, you do show it without indentation, which would be the cause of why `accessKeyId` is not indented properly.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming routingConfig is already a dict have you considered using the [to_yaml filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#formatting-data-yaml-and-json) in your template

```
routingConfig:
    {{ routingConfig | to_yaml | indent }}
```

Comment: `indent` does not, by default, indent the first line. You either need to indent the second line in the template by 4 spaces or give `indentfirst=True`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it got curly braces in the output. Updated the question